# Why does the Particle System (hair) never orient instanced objects properly?

Tags: particles, instances

I know geometry nodes are more versatile for scattering instanced objects, but sometimes i like painting with a weight map to distribute instances.

But the particle system never orients my objects the way they are in world space.  Original objects standing up on Z axis?  instances are lying down for some reason.  Switch orientation in particle menu to global Z or object Z?  Now the instances are on their other side or upside down.

Objects a certain size?  instances are about .05 that size.  Adjust the size in the particle menu from .05 to 1, and now the instances are huge. Rotate using the "phase" slider (which i don't understand why its called that) and the objects rotate in ways you weren't expecting.  Using "use object scale" or "use object rotation" in the particle menu doesn't use the object scale or object rotation.  None of it makes any sense to me.

Is there a way to have it behave normaly?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think it's something I've ever figured out the "base rules" to, rather I have just adapted by learning how to mess around with the particle object (the one from which the rest are instanced) in edit mode, and how that affects the final result. The editable values in the particles panel, I find are best used for keyframing, whereas you get the most control over the final result by modifying the instance object directly (except for particle rotations - all I can add there is that "Phase" should be thought of more of as "Phase shift" or "Phase offset").

Comment: In my answer to this question I explained about the general orientations of particles in the different systems, not that it makes anything easier but perhaps it can help when constructing intance objects to know how they will come out as particles: [Boid physics/ Particles/ The problem of lots of fish swimming backwards](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253693/boid-physics-particles-the-problem-of-lots-of-fish-swimming-backwards/255220#255220)

Comment: For the size: yes particles are at 0.05 the size of the instanced object, because that's what the default setting is - I guess the reason is that usually (or in the beginning) people used particle systems to animate thousands of particles and they wanted them small. However, if that's too small, as you know you can change the size when setting up the particle system... what do you mean with the instances are huge when you set the size to 1? It's simply the original size which I would expect at scale = 1, if that's too large for you why not set a different value between 0.05 and 1?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett The base rules of the instanced object's orientation? See the link in my comment above ;)