# Wrong rotation of objects when using scatter add-on

Tags: modeling

I have tried the pre-installed scatter add-on for the first time, and it seems to be amazing. However I encountered an issue when trying to scatter trees on a ground object or even a simple plane. As per the image below, there is a weird orientation of some trees when scattered: some instances are correct, while others are upside-down or rotated at a weird angle. I tried playing with all the scatter variables like randomization, normals, rotation and so on, but it didn't help. I tried scaling the object or the plane, or playing around with the transformation orientation or pivot point- still no success so far. I tried rotating the source tree object in edit mode so that it modifies the scatter in real time- but I couldn't fix the scatter problem. The only solution would be to rotate manually each of the scattered instances in edit mode so that they display correctly, but it would be quite time-consuming.

I tried the same with another downloaded tree model, and it has the same issues. The weird thing is that I tried scattering a simple cylinder on the same plane, and it works like a charm (including options like random scale percentage); so it has to do something with the tree geometry that I am trying to scatter.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I've made an overview on how scattered particles / boids / hair will be oriented from the emitter because it differs, maybe this helps, see my answer to this question: [Boid physics/ Particles/ The problem of lots of fish swimming backwards](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253693/boid-physics-particles-the-problem-of-lots-of-fish-swimming-backwards/255220#255220). Of course it not only depends on how the emitter orients them, but also how the mesh itself is oriented in regard to its object axes and if there is maybe a rotation not applied.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it worked. It was a rotation issue, I just cleared the rotation in object mode with 'Alt+R' and afterwards re-oriented with all faces selected the object in Edit mode so that it appeared up-right. Afterwards Scatter worked like a charm. Cheers, mate!