# How to model a simple fish?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model [the fish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iOjO.jpg) from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/255220/50044):

[image: fish]

I have attempted to create it with:

1. default cube
2. loop cut on y axis
3. scale on y axis
4. bevel, extrude, and scale for fins
5. spheres for eyes

[image: fish]

**How can I make it better/more similar to the one from the answer?** If it is possible to create procedurally/with geometry nodes, that would be even better.

[Here is my `.blend` file](https://blend-exchange.com/d/ydS8qSjm/fish.blend):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Put a cube in front of your reference image, cut it in half, give it a *Mirror* modifier, enable the *Clipping* option of the modifier:

[image]

Extrude it and scale and rotate the extrusions in order to follow the shape:

[image]

Move the faces in order to narrow the tail and head:

[image]

Create a loopcut:

[image]

Create the fins with some extrusions:

[image]

[image]

Move this edge down to round the shape:

[image]

Move this one up, etc:

[image]

Comment: @xgjxcxzk This answer comes quite close to my original fish. If you want to have exactly my fish, I could upload the file but I guess it would be a good modelling exercise if you try to get it close on your own. By the way: yes, the eye is a sphere, but the pupil is not separate it is just a different material. The thing with _Geometry Nodes_ is: this is a quite simple model, it would be unnecessarily complicated to try to get all parts in the correct dimensions and orientations and with supporting loop cuts for sharper corners... but of course you could try that as an exercise as well ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I tried making my own: https://blend-exchange.com/b/per1e1y2. How did you make it smooth/not blocky? I think I modelled it following the reference image well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBAkI.png. WIth subdiv + shade smooth, it doesn't look much of a fish anymore: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X35gw.png

Comment: @xgjxcxzk Well, I used a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier as well and shaded it smooth - you need additional loop cuts in areas where you want to preserve sharper not so rounded contours, for example the transition from body to fin and flippers

Comment: Blend: https://blend-exchange.com/b/k7nep06v, result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/peWzj.jpg